# python subprocess popen returns None

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, popen, nonetype

I have a python snippet like this:

```
self.task = subprocess.Popen("bash ./FOLDER/script.sh", cwd=some_dir, shell=True)
self.task.wait()
```

from which an exception is raised, complaining that a 'NoneType' object has no method wait(). I guess it means the Popen call returns None ? What could be the reason for that. The documentation does not mention this possibility

I'm using python 2.7.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently self.task gives a NoneType respons meaning the `subprocess.Popen()` command is likely at fault.

First thing I notice is an incorrect syntax, since you did not wrap your command line in square brackets `[]` and you did not split the arguments.

Furthermore, the Python docs state (regarding the cwd option you used):

> If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to
>   cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered
>   when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path
>   relative to cwd.

So first thing to check would be if your `script.sh` is situated in `some_dir/FOLDER/script.sh`.

If that is indeed the case, please check if you inserted the cwd-argument with the right syntax, so as a string.. Meaning `cwd="/path/to/some/dir"`.

Then, since the Python docs clearly state that:

> Using shell=True can be a security hazard

I would remove that argument. This might mean you will have to use the full path to your bash. To find out the correct path, open a terminal and execute `which bash`. Or, to be sure, `type bash`.

Then, give this a try:

```
import subprocess

self.task = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/your/bash", "./FOLDER/script.sh"], cwd="/path/to/some_dir", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) # This makes sure you will also catch any standard errors, so it allows for a bit more control. 
output, errors = self.task.communicate() # This already encapsulates .wait()
print(output.decode()) # if you'd like to check the output.
```

Read the comments in code for some further explanation..

Comment: In fact there were a mistake in code and `wait()` was called on another var than `self.task`, just like error said. I accept your answer because I learnt 2-3 things from it, thank you